# Showing slug instead of id for crud in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

im making an edit section on my laravel crud project. that when i press edit, it will redirect to the `edit.blade.php` which will call the slug instead their id. i have worked on it and it shows the error that `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::edit(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected`

my Route

```
Route::get('edit/{slug}', $url. '\productController@update');
Route::get('edit', $url. '\productController@edit');
```

my ProductController::edit()

```
public function edit(Product $product, $slug)
    {
        return view('edit', compact('product'));
    }
```

my ProductController::update()

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product, $slug)
    {
        Product::where('product_slug',$request->$slug)->update([
            'product_title' => $request->title,
            'product_slug'  => $request->slug,
            'product_image' => $request->image
            ]);

            // redirect
            return redirect('edit');
    }
```

any helps would be greatly appreciated,thanks in advance

Comment: there is no route parameter in the URI for that edit route and the update should probably be something other than a GET route

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 12):

You do not need to worry about anything. Just add below code to your Product model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

and Laravel will take care of the rest. For more information, visit below link, they have a very good explanation there:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name

Comment: Worked for me with Laravel 8, not sure if this is required however I added a 'slug' field to my table for the model.

Comment: This makes no attempt to address the error given in the question, and is at best half an answer. -1

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you have 2 parameters in your methods: `Product $product` and `$slug`. To solve this error you should remove one of them.

You also need to add `slug` parameter to your `edit` route in order to access it in your controller. And your `update` route should be `PUT` or `PATCH`.

Something like this:

```php
Route::get('products/{slug}/edit', [ProductController::class, 'edit'])
Route::patch('products/{slug}', [ProductController::class, 'update'])
```

So, you can either remove the `Product $product` and use the `$slug` to get the product:

```php
public function edit($slug)
{
  $product = Product::where('product_slug', $slug);

  return view('edit', compact('product'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $slug)
{
  Product::where('product_slug', $slug)->update([
    'product_title' => $request->title,
    'product_slug'  => $request->slug,
    'product_image' => $request->image
  ]);

  // redirect
  return redirect('edit');
}
```

Or you can remove the `$slug` and use the `Product $product` by setting `slug` as your route key and changing the route param to `product`.

```php
// Product model
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
  return 'slug'
}

// Product controller
public function edit(Product $product)
{
  return view('edit', compact('product'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
  $product->update([
    'product_title' => $request->title,
    'product_slug'  => $request->slug,
    'product_image' => $request->image
  ]);

  // redirect
  return redirect('edit');
}

// Route
Route::get('products/{product}/edit', [ProductController::class, 'edit'])
Route::patch('products/{product}', [ProductController::class, 'update'])
```

Answer (score -1):

pass id in your edit button instead of slug

```
<a href="{{url('edit/'$id'')}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" />Edit</a>
```

and change your update function

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product, $id)
{
    Product::where('id_column_name', $id)->update([
        'product_title' => $request->title,
        'product_slug'  => $request->slug,
        'product_image' => $request->image
        ]);

        // redirect
        return redirect('edit');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In laravel 10+ you can do it like this:

```php
use App\Models\Post;

Route::get('/posts/{post:slug}', function (Post $post) {
    return $post;
});
```

Comment: When answering a question, please tailor your answer to the question being asked, rather than just copying from the documentation. See also [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).